# Use Plain Text Password in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

Good Day,

I'm new and still learning in the Laravel 7 Framework. Is there a method on how I can use plain text password for my login page because on my existing database users password is only used plain text?

Comment: Plaintext passwords are dangerous.  Always encrypt and compare.  Use enters password -> encrypt and stores in db, then when user wants to log in, encrypt password -> send to server side -> server compares that encrypted form info with what encrypted data is in the database.

Comment: @tblev *hash* and *regenerate the hash to verify*. Encryption = reversible. [See this question for why they are not the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms)

Comment: If your existing DB is already plain text passwords then just wash them through [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). Seriously, PHP makes securing passwords **trivial**. There's no excuse not to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually retrieve a user then pass it to the Auth::login( $user ).
Example:

```
$user = User::where( 'email'    => $request->input( 'email' ) )
        ->where( 'password' => $request->input( 'password' ) )
        ->first();

if( $user ) {
    Auth::login( $user );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Passport, this can be done by extending `Laravel\Passport\Bridge\UserRepository` class.

```
use Laravel\Passport\Bridge\UserRepository;
use Laravel\Passport\Bridge\User;

class MyUserRepository extends UserRepository
{
    public function getUserEntityByUserCredentials(
        $username,
        $password,
        $grantType,
        ClientEntityInterface $clientEntity
    ) {
        $user = UserModel::first(['username' => $username]);
        if ($user->password == $password) {
            return new User($user->getAuthIdentifier());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you may want to bootstrap the repository to Passport via a service provider, ways to do it will depend on your authentication policy.